# Timeout from a hanging process (stuck os calls)

Tags: python

I have a python program accessing a NFS-mounted file system. Sometimes, the file system becomes inaccessible and a simple os.stat("/path/to/file") will hang the process. I have tried the following timeout wrapper snippet, but it doesn't seem effective when dealing with "bad" OS-system calls (bad in the sense that it won't return): for example, it works with:

```
with timeout(seconds=3)
   sleep(4)
```

but it doesn't work:

```
with timeout(seconds=3)
   os.stat("/nfs/mounted/filesystem")
```

Are there any other ways I can kick myself out of the hanged process?

```
class timeout:
    """
    Usage:
        with timeout(seconds=3):
            sleep(4)
    """

    def __init__(self, seconds=1, error_message='Timeout'):
        self.seconds = seconds
        self.error_message = error_message

    def handle_timeout(self, signum, frame):
        raise TimeoutError(self.error_message)

    def __enter__(self):
        signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, self.handle_timeout)
        signal.alarm(self.seconds)

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        signal.alarm(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *Watchdog Process*

For instance:

```
with timeout(seconds=3)
    watchdog_queue.put( (my_id,timeout=5) )
    os.stat("/nfs/mounted/filesystem")
    watchdog_queue.put( (my_id,clear) )
```

If the *Watchdog Process* get no `(my_id,clear)` message within *5 seconds* than kill the Process/Thread with `my_id`.

Answer (score -1):

you can try this, it's not optimized but it should work:

```
i=0
while i<200:
    try:
        os.stat("/nfs/mounted/filesystem")
        i=200
    except:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: I don't think this will work - there is no exception thrown.